# How to change Wamp 404 page to display my wordpress 404 page

Tags: wordpress, themes, http-status-code-404

I have installed WAMP for testing my WordPress theme.

But whenever a 404 occur it display the default 404 page instead of WordPress theme 404 page.

how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for where you're 404 page for Apache is located and switch it out for the wordpress one.

```
   Alias /error_html/ "/home/WebServer/www/host/error_html/"
    <Directory "/home/WebServer/www/host.ru/error_html">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /error_html/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html
</VirtualHost>
```

you can just change the `ErrorDocument 404 /error_html/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html` part.